# How to toggle Target Display Mode on iMac using a non-mac wired keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, display, bluetooth, target-display

I have a new Late 2013 rMBP and a Mid 2011 iMac. I want to use the iMac in Target Display Mode so I can operate it as a second monitor for the laptop.

I have two questions:

1. I can easily turn on TDM on the iMac using <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but cannot turn it off the same way. I have to unplug the Thunderbolt cable. Anyone know why?
2. I only have one Apple keyboard and mouse, and both are bluetooth wireless. Right now they are paired to the iMac. I will instead pair them to the laptop so I can use them on that, but I need a keyboard that can toggle TDM on the iMac. I tried using a Dell keyboard (which in my experience, Apple treats the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> as the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key) and using <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but it doesn't toggle it. Is there any hope to use a non-Apple keyboard to toggle TDM on the iMac?

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/540799/sending-key-via-ssh-or-using-mouse-to-activate-target-display-mode

Answer (score 2):

To your 2nd question: I've not been able to toggle target display mode with a non-apple keyboard, however I was able to accomplish this using the app 1Keyboard. Basically I paired the computers via bluetooth, then used 1Keyboard to send command+F2. Sending command+F2 via Apple Remote Desktop did not work. I also tried sending command+F2 programmatically, but that didn't work either. Glad to have found a solution. Both computers were running Mavericks.

Comment: 1Keyboard was the solution for me as well

Comment: 1Keyboard worked for me on an iMac running OS X 10.8 and a Macbook Pro on Yosemite.

It's a scandal Apple makes it this difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Mac and have experience both these issues, I hopefully can shed some light on the first question, but have not yet found an answer to question 2.

To turn off TDM on my late 2013 iMac (connected to a late 2011 macbook pro) I have to type in my iMac password followed by cmd +F2 - its a bit of hit and miss, but it is the only way I can get TDM to turn off without unplugging or turning off.

Comment: Hah, wow thanks. I was just able to do it by first typing my password for iMac

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualKVM](https://github.com/duanefields/VirtualKVM/releases) from duanefields on Github is free and easy to use. From the README for the project:

> Useful for those who use their iMac as a monitor for their Macbook.
>
> Automatically toggles off your iMac's Bluetooth and turns on Target
>   Display Mode when you connect a Macbook via Thunderbolt.
>
> To use, simply run. Might want to run at startup. When you plug your
>   notebook into your iMac via Thunderbolt, this extention will
>   automatically switch the iMac to Target Display Mode, allowing you to
>   use your iMac as a monitor.
>
> In addition, it will turn off the Bluetooth on the iMac, freeing up
>   your mouse and keyboard to pair with your notebook. When you unplug
>   the notebook, the iMac's Bluetooth will be powered back up and the
>   monitor restored.
>
> If you install it on your Macbook, the opposite happens. When you
>   connect to the iMac the Macbook's Bluetooth will turn on, and then off
>   again when you disconnect.
>
> Quit and control options from the status bar menu.

Comment: this app doesnt seem to work if you're using a non-mac keyboard. very irritating.